# how to handle un-fixed number of form fields in jersey

Tags: java, forms, rest, jersey

I have a REST API which accepts `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`. 
I know I can use something like `@FormDataParam("field1") String field1` to get to form field values in my rest API code. 
What I want to know is that is there any way I can handle case where number of form fields is not fixed. ie. form submitter can add more input fields from UI and then post that form. So in my REST API I can never take a call how many fields will be coming.
How can this be handled in jersey?

thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Get away with @FormParam in jersey and use the context field. Something like

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@POST
@Path("/testForSandeep")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String func() throws IOException 
{
    //gives you all params
    final Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

    //you can iterated and get whatever you want
    for(String fieldName : params.keySet())
    {
        String[] fieldValues = params.get(fieldName);
    }
    //more code
}
```

Comment: but I also have to handle file upload in same request.